# Adjective for something using plug-ins

Tags: terminology, programming, software

I'm looking for an adjective (preferably) that describes a software component as being capable of using plug-ins, or better yet, as only performing its function if it has been loaded with plugins. So, for instance, if you had a logging module that only outputs anything if you load at least one appropriate output plugin for it, you could call it an "[adjective] logger".

For the longest time, I thought "pluggable" was the right word for this, but as I've just found out, it usually means that something *can be plugged into something else* (secondary question: Is this correct?). So a "pluggable logger" would, if anything, be a plugin for the logging system as described above, when I'm looking for an adjective to describe that system itself.

I'm also open to alternative ways of formulating it that don't reduce it to a single adjective. E.g. in music production software, I've seen people refer to "plugin hosts" that can load plugins supporting specific APIs ([example](https://kx.studio/Applications:Carla)). That might work, e.g. in the logging example above, the term could be "logger plugin host". But it's quite clunky, I've never seen this term used outside of music production software and find "host" a bit confusing as it already means something very specific in networking. So I'm wondering if there are any other terms for this I should be aware of.

Comment: The term *modular* is used for this kind of architecture but can be applied to framework or component.

Comment: If the plug-in is required, perhaps *plug-in equipped module* or *plug-in fitted logger*.

Comment: For anyone interested, I ended up going with *host* after all, after finding out that it is in fact used in more general contexts (e.g.: https://pluggy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#what-is-it ).

Answer (score 1):

The suffix *-ready* might be used for this purpose:

> added to nouns to create adjectives that show what something is ready
> for
>  <sub>Source: [Macmillan Dictionary Open Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/ready_5)</sub>

*Plugin-ready* functions as an adjective:

> *It’s a plugin-ready logger.*
>
> *The logger is plugin-ready.*